# Ошибка при использовании tomcat-embed-jasper

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, wildfly

Pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <!--Для деплоя нужен scope = provided-->
        <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Для запроса к yahoo-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yql4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>yql4j-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dep</id>
        <build>
            <finalName>weatherqueue</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                        <port>9990</port>
                        <username>myname</username>
                        <password>mypass</password>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    app.run(args);
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor controllerPool() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(25);
    return executor;
}

@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    sessionLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
    return sessionLocaleResolver;
}
```

}

Делаю jms-брокер на spring. При запуске приложения с помощью tomcat всё работает как планирую. При попытке деплоя на wildfly возникают проблемы, связанные с tomcat-embed-jasper: если не поставить scoped = provided, то не задеплоится. Если ставлю  scoped = provided, то приложение на томкате не запустится.

А также после деплоя навигация между jsp-страницами не работает, пишет ошибку: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL. Эти проблемы как-то связанны? И как мне решить их?